# Should I use Service or IntentService for my android app?

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

Please correct me If I am wrong :

**1)** A *Service* is used to perform long tasks in background. A service runs in the UI thread so if there  comes a long task then it may freeze our UI. A service will continue to run independent of application as long as we tell it to stop.

**2)** An *IntentService* on the other hand is used to perform short tasks in separate thread. It automatically terminates when it finishes its task.

**What I have to do :**

1) check for location every 5 seconds

2) if there is a change in location send it to server and Update the UI with new location values

**What confuses me :**

Should I use a *Service* or *IntentService* as I need to do it continuously after 5 seconds and does not want my UI thread to become unresponsive.

This app will be used to track a vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use an `IntentService` because it finishes itself once the job is done and you would need to re-schedule it again after 5 seconds. To re-schedule it you would need either some complicated external `Timer` mechanism associated with an application `Context` or, even worse, use `AlarmManager` that will suck your battery like crazy.

I would use a Service with a `Timer` inside for scheduling `TimerTasks` each 5 seconds and on each `TimerTask` that anyway executes on a worker thread I would get the position and make an Http request.

Just don't forget to `cancel` the timer on Service's `onDestroy` method otherwise you'll leak the `Service` instance.

**EDIT**
I just noticed this `and Update the UI with new location values` ... Keep using the `Service`, but either use an `AsyncTask` for sending the request in `doInBackground` and then send a broadcast message in `onPostExecute`, either keep using the same `TimerTask` mechanism but use a `Handler` that is instantiated with a UI Looper and make UI update requests on that handler.

Comment: What are the battery implications of running a service to request location every 5 seconds

Comment: @GregEnnis: Good question, maybe this should be put as a separate SO question, but I would say this depends on each manufacturer as I don't expect each device to drain out at the same time. But if the feature request is like that, I would say to concentrate on making location requests only when the location update is really necessary. Trivial example: during the visibility period (onResume-onPause) of a relevant Activity. As soon as location updates are not necessary, stop requesting location updates and close the service. Does it answer?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) A Service is used to perform long tasks in background. A service runs in the UI thread so if there comes a long task then it may freeze our UI.

yes, but when you use service for some long task then you create thread inside it. One very important feature of services is that android system is less likely to kill your app if your if there is low memory. And if you use setForeground then it will kill your app even more less likely.

> A service will continue to run independent of application as long as we tell it to stop.

it will run in your application process, so you cant tell it will run inependently, you can of course stopp it from your app, or service can stop itself if it finished its work.

> 2) An IntentService on the other hand is used to perform short tasks in separate thread. It automatically terminates when it finishes its task.

IntentService extends Service and makes implementing Service a lot easier, it runs your code on its own worker thread. It will terminate if there is no more queued work to do.

> Should I use a Service or IntentService as I need to do it continuously after 5 seconds and does not want my UI thread to become unresponsive.

it greately depends on your task, if your job is triggered from UI by some function then go with IntentService. Bare services are rally for really long tasks, ie. like mp3 players, or if you need constant communication with server.

If your task can be issued while your app is in background, ie. it is triggered by BroadcastReceiver, then you should look into wakefull intentservice:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

it will keep your app alive for the time intentservice will process your job, otherwise android is allowed to kill your app (after broadcast onReceive returns).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `IntentService` which you can schedule using `AlarmManager`

I have done something similar in this project:

https://github.com/madhur/MapMyLocation/tree/develop/src/in/co/madhur/mapmylocation

You may check it out

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` derives from `Service` and just creates a thread for you and manages the lifecycle.

You should use an `IntentService` in combination with the newer Android [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html). In particular if you are checking user location, you can use a geofence and let the OS do the work for you - and save battery.

Answer (score 0):

About the location

there is a location distance update -> i.e if location of phone changes for more than X meters, then send the update, DO NOT ASK FOR IT EVERY 5 SECONDS , if you are in a moving vehicle, that X meters will go by fast, if you are walking, you WILL NEVER move over 5 seconds more than 3-5 meters - people will complain that your app kills their battery

Also - A service will only continue running when your app is not running, if you start it sticky. otherwise, when your app is destroyed from the application queue, so will be the service.

```
requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)
Register for location updates using a Criteria and pending intent.
void     requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
Register for location updates using a Criteria, and a callback on the specified looper thread.
void     requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
Register for location updates using the named provider, and a pending intent.
void     requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
Register for location updates using the named provider, and a callback on the specified looper thread.
void     requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent)
Register for location updates using the named provider, and a pending intent.
```

[Location api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any service than you can use feature of location API. you have to register your location manager providing latest location. If you need to use one of the service than

```
  IntentService
```

is best option for you.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                        5000 ,
                        10, new myLocationListener());
```

Here is your location listener class.

```
public class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Here you can get latest location and update to server
       //location object provides you to latest location.

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Please mark accept to this answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: I know that it will give me location update every 5 seconds but the problem is if my app terminates than it will not be able to send updates to server. What I want a reliable mechanism that will continue to send location data to server even when the app terminates. This app will be used for tracking a vehicle.

Comment: So, you have to register one alarm with 5 min of interval time when your app will close i.e.  in onDestroy() method of your launcher activity. than you can get latest location in your alarm broadcast and check whether it is updated or not. if it is updated than update it to server.

Comment: So is the locationmanager registering the requesting updates in a service? Because if it is done in the an activity(UI bound component) then the whole point of it is lost